# How to implement eraser functionality in DrawingApp?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I implement a soft eraser stroke in a CGBitmapContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800582/how-do-i-implement-a-soft-eraser-stroke-in-a-cgbitmapcontext)
>   [How can I erase UIBezierPath lines drawn on a transparent view above an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979937/how-can-i-erase-uibezierpath-lines-drawn-on-a-transparent-view-above-an-image)

In my Drawing app I want to implement Eraser Functionality.

If I have a white Background I will be erase that with change the color to white.

But, do I do if I have to erase the drawing on Background with photo?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are many possible solutions. One of them:

- you create two layers (two images). One for the background, another for the drawn stuff.
- when you "erase" you draw something. This something must mask background and
- masked result must be drawn on the "stuff" layer.

Also you can play with masks, with blending options — I think every one of this features will allow you to implement "eraser" functionality.

Comment: can you give me some sample code..I dont know about how to do blending..

Comment: You can find examples here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/27669-uiimage-blending-images-blend-modes.html It's a very common and powerful technique, so it can be found on the internet a lot.